# Deny request with environment variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using apache. I have a header variable which name is `GEO_COUNTRY`. I want something like that:

```
If GEO_COUNTRY == "USA" THEN DENY THE REQUEST
```

Is this possible with using .htaccess?

Ps: I know Stackoverflow rules, I researched it and nothing find so I couldn't try anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can deny the request if env var  **GEO_COUNTRY** is set and the value is **usa**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEO_COUNTRY} ^usa$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: One more question: How can I do this "If GEO_COUNTRY != USA" THEN DENY THE REQUEST"

Comment: just use the not char **!** . * eg: **!^usa$**

Comment: Thank you. Last question: If GEO_COUNTRY is not set then don't block this request. How can I do this?

Comment: **If env is not set ,then dont block the request**

You can do it like this :
    **RewriteCond %{ENV:GEO_COUNTRY} ^$
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]**

^$ means an empty string, The RewriteCond says that (if env variable is empty/notset ,then let the request pass through untouched/dont forbid it.)